# C++ Tile mapping for a 2D game tutorial?

Tags: mapping, 2d, tile

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a 2D top-down view game. I assume tile mapping is a pretty good start. Im using basic sprites for character and the ground tiles. Anyone know of a good tutorial and setup guide i could use?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the late answer but in my search for the same thing as you I found these results:

1. [C++ Tile Engine from Scratch -- Part 1](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/230524-c-tile-engine-from-scratch-part-1/)
2. [C++ Tile Engine from Scratch -- Part 2](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/230525-c-tile-engine-from-scratch-part-2/)
3. [C++ Tile Engine from Scratch -- Part 3](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/231078-c-tile-engine-from-scratch-part-3/)
4. [C++ Tile Engine from Scratch -- Part 4](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/232396-c-tile-engine-from-scratch-part-4/)

I hope it helps :)